# SugarCRM invoking External Web Services simple examples

Tags: web-services, sugarcrm

I have been trying to find some very,very simple exaple on how to implement invoking some external web service from Sugar CRM, all examples I found are Invoking SugarCRM,but without luck. One example, call some web  service using a button and return only one value in some field. Does someone have such links or examples? I want to learn how to integrate with some external web services?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This example helped me alot.

http://amusarra.github.io/Project/SugarCRM/REST/ClientApplication/HTMLSugarCRMRESTApplication.html

https://gist.github.com/amusarra/10076577

Comment: Links can die; please give a description of what we're supposed to see rather than just giving a link.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple tool for doing this...

http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2012/05/11/new-for-sugar-6-5-sugarhttpclient/

If you want something more advanced, you can leverage the Connections API to help out as well...

http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2013/02/15/leveraging-the-connectors-api-for-storing-external-service-api-keys/

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response I saw your posts on sugar crm forum. But still I can not find something very simple to call FROM Sugar (your first link is to call Sugar) and I need for SOAP. Do you please have some link, example, or phph files where I could see the simpliest method: how to create Additional Button in Module (on example next to Edit button-tab) . I click on that button I send some value (on example in one field "USD" in second "EUR") and I get as response value 1.123 which I will set in some field.

Comment: Could you please explain me how to do it or pass me the code if it is not too complicated? I can not find such the most simple example. Thank you

Comment: We have NuSOAP built in the app, so you could leverage that instead if you need to use SOAP